# Constant permission denied error on VBS script

Tags: windows-server-2003, vbscript

The file is created and copied to the network share but I need this to run without errors as I need to push out to users quietly. Permissions have been set to full everyone. No errors when copy to local drive.

```
'Define variables, constants and objects 

'define text file and username 

Const ForAppending = 8 
Const OverwriteExisting = TRUE 

dim WSHNetwork, UserString 
set WSHNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
UserString = WSHNetwork.UserName 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _ 
    ("" & UserString & ".txt", ForAppending, True) 

' rest 

strComputer="localhost" 
Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003 
Set objWbem = GetObject("winmgmts:") 
Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts://" & strComputer & "/root/default:StdRegProv") 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:"  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

'Go and get the currently logged on user by checking the owner of the Explorer.exe process.  

Set colProc = objWmiService.ExecQuery("Select Name from Win32_Process" & " Where Name='explorer.exe' and SessionID=0") 

If colProc.Count > 0 Then 
   For Each oProcess In colProc 
       oProcess.GetOwner sUser, sDomain 
   Next 
End If 

'Loop through the HKEY_USERS hive until (ignoring the .DEFAULT and _CLASSES trees) until we find the tree that 
'corresponds to the currently logged on user. 
lngRtn = objRegistry.EnumKey(HKEY_USERS, "", arrRegKeys)    

For Each strKey In arrRegKeys 
   If UCase(strKey) = ".DEFAULT" Or UCase(Right(strKey, 8)) = "_CLASSES" Then 
   Else 

       Set objSID = objWbem.Get("Win32_SID.SID='" & strKey & "'") 

'If the account name of the current sid we're checking matches the accountname we're looking for Then 
'enumerate the Network subtree 
       If objSID.accountname = sUser Then 
           regpath2enumerate = strkey & "\Network" 'strkey is the SID 
           objRegistry.enumkey hkey_users, regpath2enumerate, arrkeynames 

'If the array has elements, go and get the drives info from the registry 
           If Not (IsEmpty(arrkeynames)) Then 
               For Each subkey In arrkeynames 
                   regpath = strkey & "\Network\" & subkey 
                   regentry = "RemotePath" 
                   objRegistry.getstringvalue hkey_users, regpath, regentry, dapath 
                   objTextFile.WriteLine subkey & ":" & vbTab & dapath 
        Next 
                objTextFile.Close 
           End If 
       End If 
   End If 
Next 

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
objFSO.CopyFile ""& UserString & ".txt" , "\\server\testlog$\", OverwriteExisting
On error resume next
objFSO.CopyFile ""& UserString & ".txt" , "\\server\testlog$\", OverwriteExisting
If err <> 0 Then wsh.echo err.number,err.description
```

Comment: How are you executing it on the end systems? Login script? Maybe a little explanation about what it is you are trying to do with the script.

Comment: User Startup script in Group Policy

Comment: if you are running this as a startup script, it will run in the context of the machine and there will be no locally logged in user.

Comment: You could try using psexec for this.  Leave the VB script on the server, and use psexec to push out the script using the necessary credentials.

Comment: Can psexec call a computer name from a text file and continue down the list? I'm trying to have this completly automated.

Comment: Yep - take a look at the @file option - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553